# google sheet : array formula for a single cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell A1 contains : **1,5,7**

I want to a create a formula in cell A2 which output like this :
**8s,40s,56s**

So i want to grab value from A1, split it by ',' so then i get the array contains :

```
1
5
7
```

I will then multiply each element by 8:

```
1x8 = 8
5x8 = 40
7x8 = 56
```

Then add 's' to the output as follow :

```
8s
40s
56s
```

Last, i want to concatenate them back using ',' as separator to become :

```
8s,40s,56s
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(JOIN(",", SPLIT(A1, ",")*8&"s"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`arrayformula(textjoin(",",1,transpose(split(A1,","))*8&"s"))`